# Can't remove a table border. No idea where it is coming from

Tags: css, drupal, firefox, border

http://www.geneseo.edu/new_social_media_test

I am working on a new social media page for my school, and I cannot get rid of this border within my table. Under the `<thead>` and above the `<tbody>` there is this grey line that I can't seem to target. I have turned off table borders in the html and in the css, but nothing works. I can't figure out where it is coming from and its driving me crazy. Is it something from a global CSS file? Maybe one of the social media plugins at the top are messing with it? I'm out of ideas; any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, in Firefox (8.0.1 :: Mac OS 10.7), the row colors flicker when the fade is over. Absolutely no clue on that one, either.

If you are looking at the code, sorry it is such a mess. I'm new to drupal, I don't have privileges to create my own CSS files, so I had to do everything inline.
Thanks!

Edit: Here is a screenshot to clarify: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AIeq.png. I also forgot to mention that when I am in preview view in Drupal, the color turns to a light blue, but not a color I have defined anywhere (like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h7d9.png).

Comment: Is it the two grey lines in the top left you're talking about?

Comment: You should post a screenshot to clarify.

Comment: I posted a screenshot to clarify, thanks.

Comment: you are not the first one who is struggling this kind of behaviour from drupal, in drupal lot's of css are get included on one page you need to use firebug and debug which css giving that specific border effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The border is set on the `th`, not the `thead` or `tr`. There are a couple rules in css_4ea78c62a1f11df9a1a23dfccad4464e.css that target `th`, creating a bottom border:

```
th{text-align:left;padding-right:1em;border-bottom:3px solid #ccc;}

tbody th{border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;}

thead th{text-align:left;padding-right:1em;border-bottom:3px solid #ccc;}
```

Note that [`!important`](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/) is intended only for user agent stylesheets. Use the cascade and selector [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). Since the stylesheet that disables the bottom border is loaded after css_4ea78c62a1f11df9a1a23dfccad4464e.css, all you need is:

```
table th {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

You may need to limit the selector to target the chart more specifically, if there are other tables that you want to keep the border.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea where that was coming from, and couldn't get the right selectors. Thanks for the tips, too.

Comment: One thing you can do to narrow in on the element in cases like this is to delete nodes and disable CSS rules using your document inspector of choice while traversing down the document tree, reloading the page to bring the elements back. Chrome's inspector is particularly good for his. Practice editing live page style and narrowing down on elements and rules as you browse the web at large. Practicing without having some goal you need to achieve will free you to play.

Answer (score 0):

I found this CSS:

```
tbody {
border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

I disabled it in Chrome's developer tools, but it didn't have any effect. That's all I can find related to the table though, try removing it from your styles, if you can. Or overriding it.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like there is also a border-bottom on thead as well. Still haven't been able to disable it, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's this line, it's in your CSS doc.

```
thead th
{
    text-align:left;padding-right:1em;border-bottom:3px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like there is also a border-top on tbody as well. STill haven't been able to disable it, though.

Comment: The line was gone when i removed the above code. But you can search the CSS file for #CCC, because that's the color of the line. Use your editor or CTRL+F to find it.